# destructor of future object in C++ 11

Tags: c++11, future

I am reading about behaviour of thread handle destructor in C++11 in Scott Meyers' book.

Here the author is discussing whether the result can be stored in future or in promise in callee, and explaining why the result can't be stored in the caller's future:

> The result can't be stored in the caller's future, either, because
>   (among other reasons) a `std::future` may be used to create a
>   `std::shared_future` (thus transferring ownership of the callee's result
>   from the `std::future` to the `std::shared_future`), which may then be
>   copied many times after the original `std::future` is destroyed. Given
>   that not all result types can be copied (i.e., move-only types) and
>   that the result must live at least as long as the last future referring
>   to it, which of the potentially many futures corresponding to the
>   callee should be the one to contain its result?
>
> Because neither objects associated with the callee nor objects
>   associated with the caller are suitable places to store the callee's
>   result, it is stored in a location outside both. This location is
>   known as the *shared state*. The shared state is typically represented
>   by a heap-based object, but its type, interface, and implementation
>   are not specified by the Standard. Standard Library authors are free
>   to implement shared states in any way they like.

(source: [Effective Modern C++, p259](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rjhIBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=must%20live%20atleast%20as%20long%20as%20future%20object&source=bl&ots=Fl0PW3yxsU&sig=0kV5_CTklFAG0XRAmn2Cb-6Qdjk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOyumlyLzJAhWBUo4KHQYhAxgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=must%20live%20atleast%20as%20long%20as%20future%20object&f=false))

My questions are

1. If we copy a future, we have complete copy, so what are we bothered about even if original future object is deleted?
2. What does the author mean by "[Given] that the result must live at least as long as the last future referring to it, which of the potentially many futures corresponding to the callee should be the one to contain its result?"?

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: suppose we do decide to store shared state in the caller's future. Now we would like to utilize `shared_future`, meaning that we can potentially have multiple copies of said future. Suppose shared result object is non-copyable, and move only. That means that the result data can live in only one of the shared futures. If you have a hundred of `shared_future` objects pointing to shared result object, it would become a nightmare to track which future actually contains it.

Additionally, what if one of these shared futures, containing the result object, goes out of scope? That's even worse, as we would lose the result.